# Make headlines sections in category page

Tags: magento-1.9, category-products

Hello I am wondering if you can divide a category page with headlines?

Here I have a picture of my what I am troubling with, this is inside the category:

[image: Imgur picture of problem]

Comment: You want to show Lamps after Image right

Comment: No, actually the lamps are products. Im sorry for bad screenshot. So I need a new headline with example: Furniture then products under there.

Comment: You can create a category attribute for this and call them as per your need

Comment: You want to same heading for all category or different

Comment: Different heading. The headlines will be related by the products.

Comment: Do you want to display subcategories of products within the parent category? Or how else would you organize the products for each subheading?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For New Head lines text you can use `static block`. and in category display setting you have to select that `static block` to show. Static block with product option.

For this you need to do custom code and call block file followed by headline in static block. Lets say 5 headlien with file block code which call different phtml file in which you have to get product listing as you want.

OR you have to customize the category view page (`template/catalog/category/view.phtml`) and put your logic there.

Comment: Yes but I want more than one new headline, lets say 5? With products sorted and placed under the headline.

Comment: @ChrisGudn You can put all your HTML in a single static block

Comment: But how do I get products to follow the headlines?

Comment: @ChrisGudn, check updated answer

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

add your root folder then run this way `www.domain.com/category.php`

```
<?php
require_once('app/Mage.php');
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage::getModel('core/store')->load(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID));
$installer = new Mage_Sales_Model_Mysql4_Setup;
$attribute  = array(
    'type' => 'text',
    'label'=> 'Your attribute label text',
    'input' => 'text',
    'global' => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
    'visible' => true,
    'required' => false,
    'user_defined' => true,
    'default' => "",
    'group' => "General Information"
);

$installer->addAttribute('catalog_category', 'ATTRIBUTECODE', $attribute);
$installer->endSetup();
?>
```

then One attribute will be create in Category Section then you add Your tittle then call your phtml `template/catalog/category/view.phtml`

in this way

```
echo $category->getData('attribute_code');
```

Comment: This code should be inside a module installer script, not in an open PHP file.

Comment: Will add root file then also it work

Comment: Using an installer script will mean that the change works across deployments. Create in your dev box, then commit and push to production... you don't have to remember that you need to run the script... it will automatically run. Besides, do you really want to clutter up the root of the website will all of these?